# How do movies & films determine what to put in their sex scenes?

Tags: production

On a superficial level, sex sells, but someone is deciding what to put in these scenes. How do they decide?

Has someone gone out and done marketing studies to figure out exactly how much nudity to put in these and what sex acts to show? Is there a sex choreographer for film like they have fight choreographers? Articles like [this one](https://www.ranker.com/list/how-intimate-scenes-are-filmed/anncasano) make it seem like the director is making a lot of these decisions. I also see that there is an [intimacy coordinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intimacy_coordinator#:%7E:text=An%20intimacy%20coordinator%20is%20a,theater%2C%20film%20and%20television%20production.) but that person doesn't seem to do any directing.

Is there a reason they are frequently, but not always, hilariously unfaithful to real life?

Comment: Not all movie sex scenes are "hilariously unfaithful." Different plots and different genres call for varying levels of detail and verisimilitude. Actors also have a say, because a nudity waiver must be signed before they join the production, which states in detail what will and will not be shown. An actor can refuse a job if they don't like those details, and the director is bound by the waiver. The parties negotiate the details prior to signing.

Comment: @Tom So I guess what you're saying is that the question really seems way too broad to answer conclusively. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I would not say it's too broad to answer. There are many factors, and it's probably not possible to exhaustively list them, but somebody more knowledgeable than I could probably give an overview of the handful that have the most impact. I suspect Johnny Bones has the start of it: the writer and director exert the biggest control, and investors have preferences that are probably driven by the desire to sell tickets (which pushes _both_ directions).

Answer (score 1):

The screenwriter(s) is the source for the context, but the Director can make changes so that stylistically it fits their vision of how the scene should unfold.  In some cases the studio can have input, such as when they want the film to be PG but the scene in question pushes it into a possible R rating.  But, for the most part, it's squarely on the shoulders of the screenwriter(s) and Director.

Comment: But I mean, how are they deciding what goes in there? They must be catering to someone and be making deliberate decisions based on the market. I assume for that reason they omit all the realistic parts of sex. (Ex: they never show the part where postcoitous you have to clean up. They just roll off of each other and start talking or some such thing... ignoring what would realistically be the sticky mess brewing under the sheets)

Comment: @GrantCurell I think you're laboring under the misconception that every frame of a movie is carefully calculated to maximize market appeal. That's false. You also seem to believe that the market wants as much nudity and explicit sex as can be crammed into the frame. That's also false. If that were true, there'd be no difference between mainstream movies & porn -- but there _is_ a difference, and we like it that way.

Comment: @GrantCurell - You also almost never see a routine bathroom scene, unless it's for comedic effect.  Yet I'm in the bathroom about once an hour.

Comment: @Tom I'm laboring under the conception that there is a reason that sex is inserted into movies and I think we would all agree it's unlikely the reason is simply, "Because of the screenwriter's creative inclinations". I'm sure that might be the case sometimes, but I very strongly suspect that it more often than not is driven by more than that.

Comment: > for the most part, it's squarely on the shoulders of the screenwriter(s) and Director. 
To work against that, there is the specialized role of an "intimacy coordinator". Intimacy on the screen can be the result of their work, a coordinated effort - similar to an action scene, in the same way that a fist fight does not require the actors to build up rage before they act violently. See this wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intimacy_coordinator

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's determined by money. But not the way you think.

The type and amount of nudity and/or sex acts depicted in a movie are largely driven by [the MPAA ratings system](https://www.filmratings.com/RatingsGuide).  If sex acts are too explicit, it will almost certainly give the film a rating of NC-17 (the highest rating available). Most movie directors will do anything they can to avoid this, because an NC-17 rating *drastically* limits a movie's earnings potential-- parents can't take their kids to see such a movie, and many theaters [won't even show](https://www.npr.org/2012/08/21/159586654/nc-17-rating-can-be-a-death-sentence-for-movies) it.  The highest-grossing R-rated film of all time earned [over $1 billion](https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/Joker-(2019)#tab=box-office); the highest-grossing NC-17 film earned a comparatively paltry [$67 million](https://www.newsweek.com/30-highest-grossing-nc-17-rated-movies-all-time-1587560).

(It's important to note that a movie's MPAA rating is determined by people, and can be (to directors) frustratingly inconsistent. But nudity and/or sex acts will quickly bump up a movie's rating, and therefore limit its earnings potential.)

Of course, directors are not required to submit their movies to the MPAA to be rated. And movie theaters [aren't actually required](https://www.wsj.com/articles/BL-LB-46171) to enforce the ratings that are there.  But to make parents happy most theaters will not show movies that haven't been rated, making no rating even worse than a hard one.